How to make titlebar buttons look like Mac?
I know you can do this, but I have a few other requirements:

It works on all apps. For some reason, themes usually seem to not work on every app.
It doesn't change anything else about the theme. I want to keep the rest of my theme, I just want the red/yellow/green buttons.
I want to stick to GNOME and Yaru.
I can move the buttons to the left-side of the window

Similar questions have been asked, but I've never requirement #1 met.

I've been trying to solve this for weeks now. now that I post on a forum I figure it out lol. it's not perfect, but it's good enough, so maybe this will help someone in the future.
git clone https://github.com/vinceliuice/WhiteSur-gtk-theme.git --depth=1
cd WhiteSur-gtk-theme
./install.sh
echo "GTK_THEME=WhiteSur-Dark" >> /etc/environment
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout 'close,minimize,maximize:'
gnome-session-quit

Accept the logoff, log back in, and you should be good to go! I think you also need gnome extensions and turn on user themes, but I'm not entirely sure.
